# Import Android AAR inside Android Library with all dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I'm developing an Android Lib/SDK that will be consume in Android/Flutter Applications. But In our SDK we must import another SDK developed by another company.

So:
Partner.aar -> OurTeam.aar -> Project

But In the documentation says that when importing aar the dependencies are not imported to the project as well. So I had to import in the project almost everything that I used in the aar.

To the project work, I have to import the partner.aar with `implementation` in build.gradle
but if I try to build my aar it gives this error:

In the image (the black drawing are the name of the company/project and the path to them locally)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0T2J.png)
if a use `api` (since compile was deprecated) the aar does not build as well.

I would like to import all dependencies only once without having to publish the package on maven